# Outlook 2010 auto responder rule not working (Error)

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, rules

In Outlook 2010 on Windows 7 I've created a template to use as an auto responder and I set a rule to respond using the template if my name is in the "to line".

Upon receiving any message the rule reports an error but gives no explanation of what the error is.

My goal here is simply to make an auto responder, if there is a simpler way/workaround I would love any help getting the to work as I am leaving town very shortly.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the Out of Office reply?

Comment: It is a pop account and believe the Out of Office reply is only an option for exchange.  Not 100% about that though.

Comment: @Obie, you are correct: http://www.nirmaltv.com/2008/04/30/how-to-set-up-an-out-of-office-reply-in-outlook-2007/

Comment: This would be better asked on SuperUser.com

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that a POP account cannot use the Out of Office reply.  But the link I posted in the comment section, or this one from [MSFT](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/automatically-reply-to-incoming-messages-with-a-pop3-or-imap-e-mail-account-HA001122385.aspx) explain how to set up a work around for your situation.  You'll need to have Outlook running for it to work however, and configure it to automatically check for messages.

Comment: thanks, I will try that tomorrow when I get into the office and let you know if it works.